# HTML set color relative to page position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a webpage with a nav-bar that has a transparent background on the top of the website, but gets a solid black color if scrolled down.

Now I want to add a dropdown menu. It would be nice if the dropdown-menu with the options has a transparent background on top, but otherwise a solid color, because otherwise it doesn't look good.

I thought about it, but I have no clue how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: set background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5); to the dropdown? Or opacity: 0.5 to some div which you place behind the dropdown

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That could be a workaround, however no perfect solution, because a semi-transparent black dropdown under a completely transparent nabber isn't the best.

Comment: *navbar, sorry
Any other idea?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some images (upload to imgur) that would illustrate what you're trying to accomplish? And add some code for what you've tried if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JS for changing the color of navbar on-scroll, then can't you piggyback off the same function to change CSS of hover too?

Sorry if this sounds stupid, But we (at least I) can't help out more than this without you posting the code.